# Upgrading Selenium grid to 1.0.7

Tags: selenium-grid

I have just been tasked with upgrading our build system to selenium grid 1.0.7 from 1.0.3. I did not create the original instance of our selenium grid.

My problem is this: our 1.0.3 installation has a windows service running that cruise control can use. In addition, there are extra folders in our selenium-grid-1.0.3 folders such as /bin /conf that do not exist in my selenium-grid-1.0.7 folder that I just downloaded. Does anyone know how I can somehow build selenium grid so that I can run it on our Windows server 2008 machine? I notice that our bin folder for 1.0.3 has a wrapper.exe in it that calls a wrapper.conf file in our 1.0.3/conf directory. I don't have either of those in my 1.0.7 folder and I'm assuming there is some other binary I must download, but have no idea where to get it from. Anyone know how I can get the selenium grid hub service to work with 1.0.7? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the previous developer simply used Java Service Wrapper to create a service around the Selenium java files, thanks.